# How to change the icon of a .jar file/application

Tags: icons

i installed a .jar application and the icon is a box, how do i change the icon?

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on that file and choose properties. In the opened dialogue click on the box shape and in the new window choose your new Icon.

[image]